# Playing audio from ByteArray

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, mp3, audiotrack

I am new to Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE)and android ,I am getting a ByteArray from Ble Device   i have to convert and play audio from that bytearray ?? What should i do ??
I already have tried MediaPlayer and AudioTrack but they don't work in my case

Can anyone please share me solution of this using AudioTrack.

Its not possible for me to share code ,so please help me out . I don't want that Bytearray to convert to mp3 audio "file " I am getting one Bytearray from ble device every 10 milliseconds and I want to play that directly.

Comment: What does one of these ByteArrays look like? BLE is usually not the right choice to transmit audio

Comment: Its the data coming from heart rate sensor or lung rate sensor @M. Kotzjan

Comment: @M. Kotzjan Basically  analog values from sensor

Comment: So you are looking for an algorithm to transform heart rate values (e.g. beats per minute) to to audio?

Comment: Yes that's kinda it i guess @M. Kotzjan

Comment: yes actually the sensor gives audio raw PCM data  @M. Kotzjan

Comment: Could you share an example bytearray?

Comment: Try to use the solution from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542675/7473793

Comment: Thanks  @M. Kotzjan actually i tried it  but it dosen't play anything and now that constructor is deprecated  it throws IllegalStateException

Comment: The ByteArray contains 4 bytes which is just an integer only.

Comment: IllegalArgumentException*